# Issue with step #6 of the Lightning Web Components Specialist superbadge. Is there a specific import order?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, trailhead, superbadges

I've seen the recent discussions regarding the superbadge exams on Trailhead, how SFSE is not supposed to provide an answer to the problem itself, since it is an exam after all, but I think it is relevant to ask this here.

---

So, I'm stuck at the step #6 of the superbadge, the "Customize the component boatMap" part. I've customized the file as the requirements on the text, but I keep getting the message:

> Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
> **We can't find the required imports** in the component boatMap JavaScript file. Make sure the component was customized according to the requirements, including the imports from Lightning Web Components.

I'm wondering if this is one of those issues where the order of the statements might mess with the checking tool's decision. Or, more specifically: does anyone found this step to require a specific order of importing things? How many things were imported? I have five import statements in my code (I won't say what is being imported, as not to give spoilers about the challenge).

Comment: Any chance [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310615/lwc-trailhead-importing-contact-fields) (from a prerequisite badge) may be the same validation issue?

Comment: I don't think so. I've used single quotes in JS the whole time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is an import issue. I've managed to pass this part after getting some hours of sleep. There are just four required imports for this specific step and JS file. My guess is that maybe extra imports are also considered by the checking tool.

Also, the checking tool seems to be a little too picky about semicolons. Always try to use semicolons for assignments.

Answer (score 5):

I also experienced that error.

The provided comment '// this getter must be public' is significant.
Check the 'Public Properties' and 'Use Getters and Setters to Modify Data' sections in the LWC dev guide.